# spring boot configuration properties not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This is driving me up the wall trying to get spring boot @configurationproperties annotation working. So hoping someone can shed some light on this for me as to what I am doing wrong.
I have a spring boot application and it contains a application.properties on the classpath. It has a value in there of

```
server.contextPath=/test/v1
server.port=8080

spring.profiles.active=dev
vendors=me
```

I have a application.class which has the spring boot annotation and sits at the top of my package hierarchy

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I am trying to map the property vendors into a configurationproperties bean as below

```
package com.test.config;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class GlobalProperties {

    private String vendors;

    public String getVendors() {
        return vendors;
    }

    public void setVendors(String vendors) {
        this.vendors = vendors;
    }
}
```

and then call this bean from my rest controller. I know it resolves the property as when i rename it the server fails to start. In the code below the props bean is not getting autowired and is null. //code ommitted for brevity

```
package com.test.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.test.config.GlobalProperties;

@RestController
@Component
public class MController {


    //TODO should be wired in from properties file 
    @Autowired
    GlobalProperties props;


    private boolean vendorUnknown(String vendor) {
        if(props.getAllowedVendor().equalsIgnoreCase(vendor)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<?> getStatus(
            @PathVariable String id) {
        //@RequestBody Bookmark input
        if(vendorUnknown("me")) {
        System.out.println("found");
    };
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

}
```

Anybody point me to what i have done wrong please?

UPDATE:

changed the code above to be a more simplistic version with a test class to recreate the issue. See below for my pom.xml and test class

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::actuator[] -->
        <!-- tag::tests[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::tests[] -->
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Test class:

```
package com.test.controller;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    MController testController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        // this must be called for the @Mock annotations above to be processed
        // and for the mock service to be injected into the controller under
        // test.
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(testController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPropertiesMsg() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/test/1").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove `@PropertySource`. You can keep `@Component`, or if you don't, specify `@EnableConfigurationProperties(GlobalProperties.class)`.
2. Don't need `@Component` on `testController`. But I think your issue is where you're calling `vendorUnknown` method from. It's not shown in your code. If calling from the constructor, then the bean initialization has not completed yet, and `GlobalProperties props` is indeed null.

**Edit**:

Based on OP's edit, here's a fully working solution.

**DemoApplication.java**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**DemoController.java**:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    @Autowired
    private DemoProperties props;

    @GetMapping(value = "/", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getVendor() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(props.getVendors());
    }
}
```

**DemoProperties.java**:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
@Component
public class DemoProperties {
    private String vendors;

    public String getVendors() {
        return vendors;
    }

    public void setVendors(String vendors) {
        this.vendors = vendors;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**:

```
vendors=me
```

**DemoControllerTest.java**:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class DemoControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testGenVendor() throws Exception {
        String vendor = restTemplate.getForObject("/", String.class);

        assertThat(vendor).isEqualTo("me");
    }
}
```

**Problems with OP's code**:

1. **`MockMvc` doesn't use the main class**, so `EnableConfigurationProperties`is not processed. `MockMvc` or `WebMvcTest` is designed to test the web layer (duh!), not the whole app. Using either of those. the properties bean should be set by the test.
2. **`InjectMocks` fails silently**. See [Why You Should Not Use InjectMocks Annotation to Autowire Fields](https://tedvinke.blog/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/).

Comment: I am not calling from constructor but am calling from a GET method in the controller

Comment: @user1107753, Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Am not sure how much more minimal I can get from the code posted above.

Comment: @user1107753 something that runs independently and reproduces your issue.

Comment: updated the question with a simplistic example and test class. The test will fail but it demonstrates that the properties nt getting set

Comment: @user1107753, see my edit. For future reference, when someone asks for a minimal example, don't include stuff like `spring-boot-starter-actuator` or `maven-failsafe-plugin`. Minimal example, by definition, is only what you absolutely need.

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct as it does work and will benefit someone in the future. But I dont see any difference between what is written here and in my code ignoring the fact about running it with mockito. As I get the same issue when starting the application and debugging to see if the properties are populated.

Answer (score 2):

Add @EnableConfigurationProperties to your Application class to enable scanning ConfigurationProperties beans.

Comment: `@PropertySource` and `@Component` can also be removed from `GlobalProperties`

Comment: Added the @EnableConfigurationProperties to my application.class  but my props bean is still null in the controller.